# MySQL MATCH AGAINST: same score even if several words match?

Tags: mysql, scoring, match-against

I have a query like

```
SELECT SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS ap.id, ap.name,
MATCH(t.uri_slug) AGAINST('"tomatoe"') AS tag_score,
MATCH(ap.name) AGAINST('blue tomatoe' IN BOOLEAN MODE) AS name_score
FROM [...]
GROUP BY ap.id
ORDER BY (tag_score + name_score) DESC, tag_score DESC, name_score DESC
LIMIT 10
```

The result of this given query is:

```
id      | name                  | tag_score                 | name_score
--------|-----------------------|---------------------------|------------------
11622   | Holy Tomatoe          | 11.033016204833984        | 7.384857654571533
26996   | Tomatoe Max           | 11.033016204833984        | 7.384857654571533
14116   | Newblue-Tomatoe       | 11.033016204833984        | 7.384857654571533
38402   | Monster-Jam           | 11.033016204833984        | 0
...
```

As you can see, the row with id 14116 contains both words blue and tomatoe in ap.name. Even if two words match, the score is the same like if one word matches. So I tried `AGAINST('+style +mode' IN BOOLEAN MODE)` and `AGAINST('+*style* +*mode*' IN BOOLEAN MODE)` but I cannot get the desired result: the more words match, the higher score should be returned. Any ideas?

Comment: the 'blue' in 'Newblue-Tomatoe' is not matched as it isn't a *word*, rather part of a word. If you remove `tomatoe` from the second Match statement in your query that row won't be returned, proving the point.

Comment: Ok, so how to make it match even parts of words? Wildcard like * doesn't work.

Comment: Not with 'Full Text Search' indexes, as they work with 'tokens' AKA 'words'. (see the docs: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/innodb-fulltext-index.html). You could create your own relevance score by using substring searches with `locate`.